# modules finite congenerated are closed under extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules

I have to prove some properties about modules finite cogenerated, I´ve already prove that mmodules finite cogenerated are closed under submodules, finite direct sums, but I can´t see how to prove that modules finite congenerated are closed under extensions. I´ve already tried a direct prove by definition, and using the other two properties, but I don´t get something useful.
Does anybody haver any idea?
Thanks for any comment!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the category of finitely cogenerated modules is *not* closed under extensions in general.

Researching this problem led me to [this article by Wisbauer](http://reh.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/~wisbauer/classes.pdf).

You need to see theorem 6.5 which I believe, when modified for this situation, says that the finitely cogenerated modules of $Mod-R$ are closed under extensions iff $R$ is right self-pseudoinjective.

Comment: thanks, I´ve been trying to understand by that way, but I need more than I have and I know